# Value passed to Function which is bound to directive is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function in the controller that I want to call from directive on clicking a button(button in the directive). I have an `ng-click` on the button with a function that's supposed to call the controller's function. But the value passed to the controller is undefined. What am I doing wrong? I have added comments in code to help understand

This is the directive:

```
    ebApp.directive('monthDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'htmlFiles/monthDirective.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            ebObj: "=obj",
            onCl : "&" //bind function
            //countArraysc: "=countObj"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.removeDir = function (removeVal) { //directive's ng-click to call controller function
                console.log(removeVal); //shows value here but undefined in controller
                scope.onCl(removeVal); //calling controller function
            }

        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log($scope);
        }
    }
})
```

The directive's html with the `ng-click` which is supposed to call function which is supposed to call controller function:

```
div class="row monthDirC">
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign pull-right cursorC"  
          ng-click="removeDir(ebObj.costArray[count])"></span> 
    <label for="datepick" class="col-md-6">Select month</label>
```

The html that uses the directive:

```
<month-dir  ng-repeat="count in countArray" on-cl="removeDirCtrl(removeVal)" obj="ebObj.costArray[count]">
            <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
        </month-dir>
```

The controller function:

```
$scope.removeDirCtrl = function (removeVal) { // function to be called from directive
    console.log("ctrlRemove");
    console.log(removeVal); //undefined
}
```

Comment: Change the directive code for calling controller as below:                                                                       scope.removeDir = function (removeVal) { //directive's ng-click to call controller function
                console.log(removeVal); //shows value here but undefined in controller
                scope.onCl({removeVal: removeVal}); //calling controller function
            }

Comment: @Harpreet. I can't read. can you post as answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the directive code for calling controller as below:

```
scope.removeDir = function (removeVal) { 
     console.log(removeVal); 
     scope.onCl({removeVal: removeVal}); 
}
```

Focus in the argument passed to callback **scope.onCl** is **{removeVal: removeVal}**

Answer (score 0):

if you simply want to call a `function` in a `controller` you don't have to complicate the `directive` so much

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('customctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.callMe = function(name) {
    alert('Hey ' + name + '! the time now is ' + new Date());
  }
});
app.directive('monthDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: `<input type="text" placeholder="what is your name?" data-ng-model="name"></input>
    <br/><hr />
    <input type="button" value="what is the time ?"  data-ng-click="callMe(name)"></input>`,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.name = 'there';
    },
    controller: 'customctrl' //the pre-defined controller name
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller='customctrl'>
  <month-dir></month-dir>
</body>

</html>
```